# The Fifth Gamma Matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory

This is regarding $\gamma^5$, the fifth gamma matrix in quantum field theory. I know its defining properties, namely,

$$\gamma^5= -i\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3 $$

with $\{\gamma^5,\gamma^{\mu}\}=0$ and $(\gamma^5)^2=1$, but so far all I've used these for is to help prove some gamma matrix identities.

It seems obvious to me that $\gamma^5$ is dependent on our representation (e.g. Weyl or Dirac), so my original idea that it's useful because of invariance on choice of basis seems wrong.

What do we like about $\gamma^5$?

Comment: In the full Standard model, certain Feynman rules incorporate $\gamma^5$, e.g. in the charged current interaction vertex. In addition, the fifth gamma matrix can be used to construct axial vectors and pseudo-scalars with spinors.

Comment: So it's just a notation to denote the product of the gamma matrices? Because this product just so happens to be useful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One reason why $\gamma^5$ is important is because it corresponds to a symmetry of the massless Dirac Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L} = i \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi
$$
and the global transformation:
$$
\psi \to \psi' = e^{i \alpha \gamma^5} \psi \tag{1}
$$
Then using the identity:
$$
\{ \gamma^5,\gamma^\mu \} = 0
$$
we can show:
$$
\gamma^\mu e^{i \alpha \gamma^5} = e^{-i \alpha \gamma^5} \gamma^\mu
$$
Therefore, it is easy to see that:
$$
\bar{\psi} \to \bar{\psi}' = \bar{\psi} e^{ i \alpha \gamma^5}
$$
Thus, we see that the transformation expressed by equation $(1)$ is a symmetry of the massless Dirac Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{L}' = \mathcal{L}
$$
which is known as the axial symmetry. This symmetry will play an important role in the Standard Model and its [anomalies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly). I'm sure you will study this at some point in the future.

Edit:

As innisfree mentions in the comments, using the $\gamma^5$ matrices, we can form the Lorentz invariant projection operators:
$$
P_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2} ( \mathbb{1} \pm \gamma^5)
$$
such that:
$$
P_+ P_+ = P_+
$$
$$
P_- P_- = P_-
$$
$$
P_+ P_- = P_- P_+ = 0
$$
(Note that the above three equations are valid regardless of the representation used.) In the chiral representation, they act on the Weyl spinor as:
$$
P_+ \psi = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \psi_R \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
P_- \psi = \begin{pmatrix} \psi_L \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
$$
In addition, for an any representation of the Clifford algebra, we use $\gamma^5$ to define the left- and right-handed parts of the field $\psi$:
$$
\psi_R  = P_+ \psi
$$
$$
\psi_L = P_- \psi
$$

Comment: true, but surely most useful feature is that it is a projection operator that gives the chiral parts of a spinor?

Comment: @innisfree Yeah I agree, but this is (often) one of the first things you learn when you come across the $\gamma^5$ matrix (and so I kind of assumed the OP has already seen this). I thought it would interesting for the OP to see this symmetry

Comment: @Hunter Thanks for the edit. You were right, I have seen this property of the fifth gamma matrix (it appears in any QFT text) but not in as much detail. The symmetry was also very helpful as I hadn't realised\seen it before

Comment: @user13223423 happy to hear that. I didn't pay much attention to the axial symmetry the first time I came across it. But once you will study the SM, you'll realize it is very important. (Personally, I think anomalies are fascinating).

Answer (score 2):

In the standard model, and more generally in quantum field theory, the fifth gamma matrix has several uses. The charge current interaction between $\psi_{u,d}$, $\psi_{d,u}$ and a $W^{\pm}_\mu$ carries a factor of

$$V = \frac{ig}{\sqrt{2}}\gamma_\mu \frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}$$

In addition, the fifth gamma matrix can be used to construct Lagrangians with pseudo-scalars, e.g. $\bar{\psi}\gamma^5 \psi$, or axial vectors such as $\bar{\psi}\gamma^5 \gamma^\mu \psi$.